# making the editor more WSWYG

Tags: css, wordpress, wp-editor

I need to remove the title from the twentytwenty theme - no problem doing this by removing it in the template of my child theme.  However it still shows in the WP editor. Since it is in a divider as below:

`<div class="editor-post-title">`

I have tried adding a CSS like:

```
.editor-post-title {
  display:none;
}
```

This works perfectly when I try it locally, in my browser editor -  but it does not work when I insert that CSS in my style sheet... any thoughts ?

Comment: Consider that removing the post title field from the editor would mean that the input field for it also doesn't appear when you create a *new* post or page, so that you *can't* define a title - I suppose you wouldn't want that (?)

Answer (score 1):

Your theme's stylesheet only loads on the frontend (generally).

[Try this article if you want to add various styles to the editor](https://richtabor.com/add-wordpress-theme-styles-to-gutenberg/).

Or for a quick-and-dirty fix you could potentially do something like this, but technically the above way is probably better and less hacky:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'remove_title' );
function remove_title() {
    echo '
        <style>
           .editor-post-title {
               display:none;
           }
        </style>
    ';
}
```